# Button for jQuery Date Range Picker to send 'from' and 'to' dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to create a Date Range Picker with jquery, this part works ok, but can't finish button, which must grab these two dates and push them to another page. As shown below

```
<script>
var jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("btnsend").click(function() {
           var pathname = window.location.pathname;
            var url = "/customlink/?datein="+jQuery('#startDate').val()+"&dateout="+jQuery('#endDate').val();
            //jQuery("#iframe-id").attr("src", url);
            window.location.href=url;
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>
```

Now when I click on button. it doesn't react.

I expect when user choose `from -22/11/2019` + `to 24.11.2019` and clicks on `btnsend`, it sends him to `domain.name/pagename/?datein=22/11/2019&dateout=24/11/2019`

Full code uploaded: https://jsfiddle.net/Stzzz/bwp6jtsq/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle controls are named "from" & "to" but you're trying to access them by "startDate" & "endDate".

You are also missing the id selector when hooking up your click event.

```
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

    jq(document).ready(function() {
        jq("#btnsend").click(function() {
            var pathname = window.location.pathname;
            var url = "/customlink/?datein="+jq('#from').val()+"&dateout="+jq('#to').val();
            //jq("#iframe-id").attr("src", url);
            window.location.href=url;
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but after I made these changes, calendar doesn't show any pop-up on click, what could it be? You could see it also on https://jsfiddle.net/Stzzz/bwp6jtsq/12/

Comment: @Stz You'll also have to change any `$` in the javascript section to `jq`. I meant to put that in the answer too, sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/oaxb7szg/